strcmp with array of pointers
I am working on a function to sort a array of pointers to an array of strings. I am done building the code but it crashes without an error message. The debugger tells me that it crashes at the if(strcmp(list_ptr[j]...)) line. I dont know what I did wrong.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort_strings(char *list_ptr, int max_subscript);

int main()
{
    char list[][20] = { "Hallo", "Kaller", "Hirsch", "Annomy", "Musik" };
    char *list_ptr[5] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        list_ptr[i] = list[i];
        /*
        printf("Pointer: %p\n", list_ptr[i]);
        printf("List: %p\n", list[i]);
         */
    }

    sort_strings(list_ptr, 5);

    return 0;
}

void sort_strings(char *list_ptr, int max_subscript)
{
    int smallest_string = 0,
        i = 0,
        j = 0;

    char *temp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < max_subscript; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < max_subscript; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(list_ptr[j], list_ptr[i]) < 0) //if array[i+1] is smaller than array[i]
                smallest_string = j;
        }
        temp = list_ptr[i];
        list_ptr[i] = list_ptr[smallest_string];
        list_ptr[smallest_string] = temp;
    }
}


Solved:
the argument int hte prototype and in the actual function must be of type "char *list_ptr[]). I forgot the [].
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort_strings(char *list_ptr[], int max_subscript);


int main()
{
    char list[][20] = {"Hallo", "Kaller", "Hirsch", "Annomy", "Musik"};
    char *list_ptr[5] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            list_ptr[i] = list[i];
            /*
            printf("Pointer: %p\n", list_ptr[i]);
            printf("List: %p\n", list[i]);
            */
        }

    sort_strings(list_ptr, 5);


    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("[%d]%s\n",i + 1, list_ptr[i]);


    return 0;
}

void sort_strings(char *list_ptr[], int max_subscript)
{
    int smallest_string = 0,
        i = 0,
        j = 0;

    char *temp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < max_subscript; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < max_subscript; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(list_ptr[j], list_ptr[i]) < 0) //if array[i+1] is smaller than array[i]
            {
                smallest_string = j;
                temp = list_ptr[i];
                list_ptr[i] = list_ptr[smallest_string];
                list_ptr[smallest_string] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}


the compiler would have told you if you had enabled the warnings ;-)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort_strings(char *list_ptr[], int max_subscript);

int main() {
    char list[][20] = {"Hallo", "Kaller", "Hirsch", "Annomy", "Musik"};
    char *list_ptr[5] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        list_ptr[i] = list[i];
    }

    sort_strings(list_ptr, 5);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("[%d]%s\n",i + 1, list_ptr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void sort_strings(char *list_ptr[], int max_subscript) {
    int smallest_string = 0,
        i = 0,
        j = 0;

    char *temp =\0;

    for(i = 0; i < max_subscript; i++) {
        smallest_string = i;  
        for(j = i + 1; j < max_subscript; j++) {
            if(strcmp(list_ptr[j], list_ptr[smallest_string]) < 0) {
                smallest_string = j;
            }
        }
        temp = list_ptr[i];
        list_ptr[i] = list_ptr[smallest_string];
        list_ptr[smallest_string] = temp;
    }
}


Declaring 'temp' to \0 make it easier

2.initialize smallest_string in outer loop makes it to reset it value each  time
3.function should me in type "char *list_ptr[] ,so it's a major reason  as you told. I think so these changes will help you to
overcome such difficulties.Thank you

There are multiple problems in the code:

the first argument of sort_strings should be defined as char *list_ptr[] or char **list_ptr (both forms are equivalent for a function argument).

max_subscript is not a valid subscript, it is the count of elements in the array, the name is misleading.

smallest_string does not get the index of the smallest string in the rest of the array, just that of the last one that is smaller than list_ptr[i].

the index variables should have type size_t and you should pass the actual array length, not a hardcoded value 5.

you do not output anything so there is no way to tell if the program is successful.


Here is a modified version:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort_strings(char **list_ptr, size_t count);

int main(void)
{
    char list[][20] = { "Hallo", "Kaller", "Hirsch", "Annomy", "Musik" };
    size_t count = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);
    char *list_ptr[sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0])];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        list_ptr[i] = list[i];
    }

    sort_strings(list_ptr, count);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%s\n", list_ptr[i]);

    return 0;
}

void sort_strings(char **list_ptr, size_t count)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        size_t smallest_string = i;
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(list_ptr[j], list_ptr[smallest_string]) < 0)
                smallest_string = j;
        }
        if (i != smallest_string) {
            char *temp = list_ptr[i];
            list_ptr[i] = list_ptr[smallest_string];
            list_ptr[smallest_string] = temp;
        }
    }
}

